# Angular Open Div Below Current Row

Tags: angularjs

I'm using Angular JS and need to open a div of related content (with the class of `.info-bg` )under the selected element row. So if I click row 1 it opens the hidden div under row 1. If I click row 2 content it appears under row 2. I am however at a bit of a loss as to the best way to accomplish this, any help would be appreciated. Here is a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Auzy/pen/yedQmm) of what I have done thus far.

My HTML:

```
<div data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="starWarsCtrl">
  <input type="text" id="query" data-ng-model="query"/>
  <div class="bscroll">
    <ul>
        <li class="box" data-ng-repeat="i in data | filter : {cat: 'jedi'} : true | filter:query |orderBy: orderList" data-ng-click="select(i)">
          <h2>{{i.name}}</h2>
          <p>{{i.cat}}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
   <div class="info-bg" data-ng-if="selectedItem">
    Name: <span data-ng-bind="selectedItem.name"></span><br>
    Index: <span data-ng-bind="selectedItem.index"></span>
    <div data-ng-if="selectedItem.cat">
        Category: <span data-ng-bind="selectedItem.cat"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bscroll">
        <ul>
        <li class="box" data-ng-repeat="i in data | filter : {cat: 'smuggler'} : true | filter:query |orderBy: orderList" data-ng-click="select(i)">
          <h2>{{i.name}}</h2>
          <p>{{i.cat}}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

MY JS:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate'])

.controller('starWarsCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
    {"name": "Obi-Wan Kenobi",
     "index":88,
      "cat": "jedi"},
    {"name": "Yoda",
     "index":69,
      "cat":"jedi"},
    {"name": "Lando",
     "index":31,
      "cat": "smuggler"},
    {"name": "Han Solo",
     "index":90,
      "cat": "smuggler"},
    {"name": "Darth Vader",
     "index":98,
      "cat": "sith"},
    {"name": "Jar-Jar Binks",
     "index":80,
      "cat": "alien"},
    {"name": "Mace Windu",
     "index":45,
      "cat": "jedi"},
    {"name": "Chewy",
     "index":76,
      "cat": "smuggler"}
  ];

  $scope.select = function (item) {
    $scope.selectedItem = item;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the 'best' way here is to add a second hidden div underneath the second set of items. This isn't very DRY, so instead you might consider adding a custom directive instead - this will allow you to create multiple sets with corresponding hidden divs in a DRY manner.

See the following AngularJS documentation for writing your own directives: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

So imagine you created a directive called `filtered-set`, and attached it to your module:

```
.directive('filtered-set', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'filered-set.html'
  };
});
```

And then create `filtered-set.html` template with:

```
  <div class="bscroll">
    <ul>
      <li class="box" data-ng-repeat="i in items" data-ng-click="select(i)">
        <h2>{{i.name}}</h2>
        <p>{{i.cat}}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="info-bg" data-ng-if="selectedItem">
    Name: <span data-ng-bind="selectedItem.name"></span><br>
    Index: <span data-ng-bind="selectedItem.index"></span>
    <div data-ng-if="selectedItem.cat">
      Category: <span data-ng-bind="selectedItem.cat"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And then use the following in your HTML, replacing the two repetitions of the items/info HTML in your original code:

```
<filtered-set items="data | filter : {cat: 'jedi'} : true | filter:query |orderBy: orderList"></filtered-set>
```